# How to use decimal type in EF6 code first

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I just wanted to ask if there is a way to represent a number (oracle database) in the model as a decimal with precision.

I think the way i do it should work, but i get strange error messages.

OnModelCreating:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().Property(x => x.Id).HasPrecision(9, 0);
```

Data type is decimal.

At runtime i get the Error:

```
(7,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Decimal[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=9,Scale=0]' of member 'Id' in type 'Application' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=9,Scale=0]' of member 'ID' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Application'.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what is your oracle datatype?

Comment: number(9,0) in this case

Comment: so your number in oracle only has precision to the whole number level but you are specifying it has precision?  Why not use number to int?

Comment: The database i work with has a lot of numbers with different precisions, so i wanted to represent them all as decimals in code. I know i can always use integers, but i'm surprised this is not working.

Comment: Oracle numbers with no precision go to Ints by default and those with precision go to decimals. You could try adding modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnType("decimal").HasPrecision(9, 0); https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featLINQ.htm